# Clarifying the 'mutate' function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

Are both versions of the code involving mutate below the same?

To give a bit of context, the exercise is to create a column called 'guests' that combines other columns that are 'adults, babies and children'.

```
example_df <- bookings_df %>%
  mutate(guests = adults + children + babies)
```

**Code version 2:
**

```
example_df <- bookings_df %>%
  mutate(guests = adults, children, babies)
```

Are both correct? I would have thought that in both cases, the 'guest' column would replace the adult, children and babies column, but I can see all columns when I view the data frame?

I tried running both versions of code but not seeing any difference

Comment: The 2nd one will set guests equal to the adults column (either creating or updating the guests column), and will leave unchanged the children and babies columns (assuming they exist).

Comment: Could you edit your question to share the output of `dput(bookings_df)`?

Comment: You might look at the `transmute` function if you want to both modify columns and specify which columns should remain. It's like combining `mutate` + `select`.

Comment: @JonSpring `transmute` is equivalent to `mutate(.keep = "none")` as the documentation states.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::mutate()` can both create new variables and overwrite existing ones. Using a shortened version of the supplied sample database `mtcars`, if you ask R to interpret the code:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars[1:5, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")]

mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(mpg, cyl)
```

You aren't asking it to *do* anything to the columns `mpg` and `cyl`, so it returns the exact same data frame (essentially does nothing):

```
#                    mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360
```

If you ask R to interpret the following command:

```
mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(mpg = mpg ^ 2, cyl)
```

You're asking R to (1) overwrite the `mpg` column with the squared value of `mpg`, and (2) do nothing to `cyl` - so it returns the squared value and same value for these columns, respectively.

```
#                      mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         441.00   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     441.00   6  160
# Datsun 710        519.84   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive    457.96   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout 349.69   8  360
```

In your first code, you are creating a new column, `guests` by summing three variables. Analogously:

```
mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(guests = mpg + cyl + disp)
```

This creates a new column, `guests`, (doesn't overwrite) and returns it the sum of the three columns:

```
#                    mpg cyl disp guests
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160  187.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160  187.0
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  134.8
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258  285.4
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360  386.7
```

The second code you provided (1) asks R to create a new column, `guests`, which is equal to the value `adults`, then (2) *do nothing* to `children` and `babies`. Analogously:

```
mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(guests = mpg, cyl, disp)
```

Returns a new column, `guests` which is equal to `mpg`, and does nothing to `cyl` or `disp`

```
#                    mpg cyl disp guests
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160   21.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160   21.0
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108   22.8
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258   21.4
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360   18.7
```

So the first one is correct if your goal is to combine the three variables, and the second one is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The versions are different. In the first example `guests` is the sum of `adults + children + babies`, and in the second example `guests` is just `adults`.

I think you are looking for the argument `.keep = "none"`. Use it in your different mutate examples, it might help you understanding it. Also, take a look at `?mutate` to learn more about the function and the `.keep` argument.